Standalone Table Invocation Using NextPrime to Generate Sequence of Division of Integers
My objective is as follows:

Create a sequence of numbers where the denominator is always the next even number (starting with 2) and the numerator is always the next prime (starting with 2).

My first thought was to use Table, but I couldn't figure out how to keep just a single aspect of a result from each evaluation to feed into the next without declaring a variable outside of the call to Table. E.g.,
y=1;    
Table[y = NextPrime[y]; y/x, {x, 2, 20, 2}]

gives me the correct values, but needs a variable declared outside of the call to Table.
I understand that there are other ways of achieving the sequence objective, but I'm particularly interested in the more general question of being able to write something as the expr argument in Table that will be able to reuse one of its outputs or a part of its output.
Is there a way to generate such a sequence using Table, having it generate a result and then taking part of that result and feeding it back into the next evaluation of Table?

Table[Prime[n]/(2 n), {n, 1, 10}]

[extended comment]
It's difficult to figure out exactly what you're asking. If you want Table specifically to perform operations on previous intermediate results, then you will need to use some sort of variable to manage state. It sounds like you want to avoid managing such statefulness yourself. So, the answer is simply "no". But, there are several constructs available to you to do exactly the kind of thing you're asking for--they just aren't Table. Look at Nest(List), Fold(List), FoldPair(List), SequenceFold(List), NestWhile(List), FixedPoint(List) (and probably others).

OK, thanks. I'm fine with it being impossible. It's just that as I was ruminating on the problem, I thought that perhaps a pure function could be constructed that recursed and which I could somehow feed part of it back into itself.

Your description doesn't match you expected result. This reproduces your expected result:
Divide @@ Comap[{#*2 &, Prime}][Range[10]]

Since you asked specifically about using Table, I'd recommend what @azerbajdzan suggested in the comments, but altered to match your expected output:
Table[2*i/Prime[i], {i, 1, 10}]


Thanks for that. I had seen that the use of Prime would work for me, but I was more interested in the general question of  how/whether a construct for feeding a part of a result back into itself was possible with a function such as Table, i.e., is there a way to make what I wrote work without declaring an outside variable? I'm going to update my question to try to make that pellucid.

Table[Prime[n]/(2 n), {n, 1, 10}]

NestList[NextPrime[Numerator[#]]/(Denominator[#] + 2) &, 3/4, 8]


$$\left\{1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{8},\frac{11}{10},\frac{13}{12},\frac{17}{14},\frac{19}{16},\frac{23}{18},\frac{29}{20}\right\}$$
$$\left\{\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{8},\frac{11}{10},\frac{13}{12},\frac{17}{14},\frac{19}{16},\frac{23}{18},\frac{29}{20}\right\}$$
